# PDF Generation using Dompdf in codeigniter redirects to a 404 page in case of large pdf files

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to generate pdf file in codeigniter using Dompdf library. Currently the PDFs are being generated for html with small content without any issues, But when the size of the content increases over 20000 characters, the script breaks and redirects to a 404 page.

The following is the Codeigniter controller function that i am using to generate the pdf.

```
public function generatePDF(){
    $this->load->model('SmartGraduatesApplicationmodel');  
    $result['result']=$this->SmartGraduatesApplicationmodel->smartGraduateApplicationPDF($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
    $html = $this->load->view('smart_graduates_application/smartGraduateApplicationPDF', $result, true);
    pdf_create($html, 'SMART_Graduate_Application');

}
```

I have already tried increasing the Max execution time, Max input time and Memory Limit with no luck.

Can you help me with your ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors recorded by codeigniter?

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/pdf-generation-using-dompdf

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort out the above issue. When using Dompdf with nested tables and large content in html, this issue seems to happen. To fix the issue, we need to use DIV instead of TABLE incase of large content in html.